# iOS App not detecting Bluetooth 2.0 headset even when the ipad is showing the device name in Bluetooth connected list

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

In my ipad when I go to Bluetooth Setting page I can see my Samsung headset device (HM 1100) in the connected list. However when I use the following code I could not get any accessories.

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager]
                                connectedAccessories];
        EAAccessory *accessory = nil;

        for (EAAccessory *obj in accessories)
        {
            NSLog(@"Found accessory named: %@", obj.name);
        }
```

Is there a way for an app to detect which bluetooth devices are connected to the ipad? Is there any way to list any unknown bluetooth peripherals in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, "Classic Bluetooth" devices are exposed as their underlying service object, not as Bluetooth objects, so a headset is visible as an audio path in the `AVAudioSession` class.

The External Accessory framework is used to interface with devices that are certified under the MFi program.

Answer (score 0):

i have found that answer in [how to find Bluetooth audio devices in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896528/how-to-find-bluetooth-audio-devices-in-ios)

This is the base code:

```
// portDesc.portType could be for example - BluetoothHFP, MicrophoneBuiltIn, MicrophoneWired
NSArray *availInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
int count = [availInputs count];
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDesc = [availInputs objectAtIndex:k];
    NSLog(@"input%i port type %@", k+1, portDesc.portType);
    NSLog(@"input%i port name %@", k+1, portDesc.portName);
}
```