# AVRCP Profile for Bluetooth- iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, avrcp

I have connected Bluetooth with GATT profile using CoreBluetooth framework in objective-C.

I want to connect Blutooth with AVRCP profile.

How can I use the AVRCP Blutooth profile ?

Any reference/sample code will helpful.

Comment: You can't connect to legacy Bluetooth devices in your app. The user can pair and connect via settings. Once it is connected you can select the audio destination using AVAudioSession - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896528/how-to-find-bluetooth-audio-devices-in-ios

Comment: @Paulw11: With CoreBluetooth framework we can't connect external devices.  But, Can we connect by using ExternalAccesoryFramework ?

Comment: You can use that framework for legacy mFI devices but not for generic devices such as AVRCP as far as I know